# Receive email alert when someone I follow on Twitter posts specific keyword

Tags: email, monitoring, twitter, alert

I would like to receive an email alert(within 24hours would be fine but hourly would be better), when someone I follow on twitter posts a specific keyword.

That keyword is "sale" so it is very generic without narrowing down to specific companies I follow. Also it happens very rarely maybe once a year.

I have found various services which perform something similar, many of them defunct.

My preference would be for a service which does not require my twitter password.

Failing that, tips appreciated on rolling your own(cronjob to get twits, then grep for keyword, then mail ?) but that would be a separate question better suited for Stack Overflow

---

EDIT:
I am trying both IFTTT and Zapier, IFTTT does not seem to offer AND conditionals (I can not filter by username AND keyword) so it is very limiting to only filter by username OR a single keyword.
 Zapier offers additional AND / OR conditions . Time to wait for that big Jetbrains sale again!

---

EDIT2:
As suggested, I entered a Twitter Advanced Search query and got back this URL:
https://twitter.com/search?q=sale%20from%3Ajetbrains&src=typd

How is that going to be converted to RSS ? I was searching and it looks like Twitter has deprecated RSS feeds and you have to do some workarounds.

So instead of RSS I just used IFTTT Twitter option for search and entered the following query

```
sale from:jetbrains
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) (If This Then That) for this.

It is a cloud solution that is meant to couple various cloud services.

There is already a recipe that does exactly this. 
You do not need to enter your twitter handle or password.
It uses an RSS feed from twitter which contains your keyword, when a new entry occurs an e-mail will be sent.

https://ifttt.com/recipes/68383-twitter-keyword-to-email

You can adjust this recipe to use a different RSS feed generated by different search results.
To generate this RSS feed see the [Advanced Search page on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search-advanced).

Comment: This sounds very close to what I want, but how would I limit the RSS feed to only specific handle(s)? I do not want to receive 1000s of alerts for ALL sales on Twitter :)

Comment: You can write your own search query, and use that RSS feed in the IFTTT recipe.
https://twitter.com/search-advanced

I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Well, there was no RSS feed but I could make IFTTT use Twitter search.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my website https://www.MyTweetAlerts.com it offers those features you are requesting.